# Testing PUT methods on a RESTful web service

Tags: html, http, rest

I have a simple RESTful web service and I wish to test the PUT method on a certain resource. I would like to do it in the most simple way using as few additional tools as possible.

For instance, testing the GET method of a resource is the peak of simplicity - just going to the resource URL in the browser. I understand that it is impossible to reach the same level of simplicity when testing a PUT method.

The following two assumptions should ease the task:

1. The request body is a json string prepared beforehand. Meaning, whatever is the solution to my problem it does not have to compose a json string from the user input - the user input is the final json string.
2. The REST engine I use (OpenRasta) understands certain URL decorators, which tell it what is the desired HTTP method. Hence I can issue a POST request, which would be treated as a PUT request inside the REST engine. This means, regular html form can be used to test the PUT action.

However, I wish the user to be able to enter the URL of the resource to be PUT to, which makes the task more complicated, but eases the testing.

Thanks to all the good samaritans out there in advance.

**P.S.**

I have neither PHP nor PERL installed, but I do have python. However, staying within the realm of javascript seems to be the simplest approach, if possible. My OS is Windows, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the Poster add-on for Firefox. You can find it [over here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/).

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As well as providing a means to inspect HTTP requests coming from desktop and web applications, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) allows you to create arbitrary HTTP requests (as well as resend ones that were previously sent by an application).

It is browser-agnostic.

Comment: +1 for the information, but could you be more specific? Given a json string and a URL how to I generate the respective PUT request?

Comment: @mark: Fiddler is GUI based, so giving you a full run down of the steps is impractical. However, it has documentation and you should be able to figure it out once the GUI is in front of you.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/restclient/#) firefox plugin (you can not use an URL for the message body but at least you can save your request) but also would recommend [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) on the command line.
Maybe you should also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087185/367285) SO question.

Comment: RESTClient seems more or less equivalent to Poster, though I like more the way Poster treats the content-type request header.